# Bluetooth problem in hp probook laptop

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, hp

I am new to this community. I have been using ubuntu for many years when i previously used the laptop i havent shown bluetooth window so I thought my laptop don't have a bluetooth module. This laptop is around 8 years old when i transferred it from ubuntu 18.04 to ubuntu 22.04 i faced a graphics driver issue but  i resolved it. Also from the beggining the wifi worked fine. that time when i used lspci i was shocked to see that my laptop  has a bluetooth module. I tried too much bu i cant turn the bluetooth on. So i just boot it on windows 10 by a pendrive and it worked. Can anyone please find a solution. I have posted a picture below you can see it. Thanks in advance. The laptop is Hp probook 4540s with an intel core 13 3110m processor and intel 4000 serise igpu the wifi and bluetooth combo adapter is  Ralink corp.RT3290. The present kernel version is 6.3
. The wifi works properly now .

[lspci test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUPtH.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetooth is not supported in the Linux kernel, you can try the following PPA, first check `mokutil --sb` as Secure Boot needs to be disabled then

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:blaze/rtbth-dkms
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rtbth-dkms
```

Reboot